# ComboBox2 depend on ComboBox1 selected items and datagridview1 depend on ComboBox2 selected item C# windows application

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

`        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-NGRLFB4\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dboo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****");
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable table;
        DataRow dr;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT Going_Id, LeavingFrom FROM LeavingAndGoing";
            comboBox1.DataSource = getData(query);
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "LeavingFrom";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Going_Id";

```
    }

     public DataTable getData(string query)       
     {           
         command = new SqlCommand(query, con);  
         adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);     
         table = new DataTable();        
         adapter.Fill(table);     
         return table;  
     }

     private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         int val;          
         Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out val);
         string query = "SELECT ID, GoingPlace, Id_Gonig FROM GoingTable Where Id_Gonig =" + val;
         comboBox2.DisplayMember = "GoingPlace";
         comboBox2.ValueMember = "Id_Gonig";
         comboBox1.DataSource = getData(query); 

     }
     private bool button1_Clicked = true;


     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         try
         {

             if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex < 0)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Place Where You Are Going");
                 button1_Clicked = false;
             }

             else
             {

                 int val;
                 Int32.TryParse(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString(), out val);
                 string query1 = "SELECT ID, Departing_Time, STARTING_COUNTER, END_COUNTER, COACH_TYPE, FARE, ARRIVAL_TIME FROM Seat_Information Where SI_ID = " + val;
                 dataGridView1.DataSource = getData(query1);
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
     }`
```

When I am trying to display datagridview1 depend on ComboBox2, It just displaying depend on ComboBox1. But I want that comboBox2 will have to depend
on comboBox1 and datagridview1 will have to depend on both comboBox1 and comboBox2.
What should I do to solve this problem??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is my code Sir I edit it. I hope you will understand my problem and help me to solve.